# Module not found:

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Всем привет. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ходить по путям, то все ок. Может какая-то ошибка с index.ts?

Алиасы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Алиасы неправильно настроены, tsconfig прикрепите.

Comment: @xydope 
прикрепил

Comment: зачем вы картинки прикрепляете? Прикрепите весь файл tsconfig ТЕКСТОМ, а также укажите какая у вас структура каталогов. Да и посмотрите пусти, по которым вы импорт делаете и по которым ts пытается найти компоненты.

Comment: добавьте `/*` в ключ алиаса, получится `"@/components/*":[...]`